# Finding rows containing special characters and deleting entire row

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I want to delete rows that contains special text, in this case, it is "YES".

I have tried writing the following code, however it does not appear to loop through all the cells, therefore unable to delete all the rows when I run it.

```
Sub FilterNo()
    Dim tablerange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Set tablerange = Range("H1", Range("H1").End(xlDown))
    For Each cell In tablerange
        If cell.Value = "YES" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Before I run it, I had 10 rows containing YES:

[image]

When I run it, there are 5 lesser rows, but there still are rows containing YES.

[image]

How do I fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rows below will shift up after each deletion. You can potentially miss checking some rows as it move up to fill the deleted space.

Option1: Delete rows in reverse order (from bottom to top)

```
Sub FilterNo1()
    Dim lstR As Long, i As Long
    lstR = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Rows
    For i = lstR To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "H").Value = "YES" Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Option2：Delete all rows at once after the For loop, rather than row-by-row within the loop. This is more efficient than option 1.

```
Sub FilterNo2()
    Dim tablerange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rngTarget As Range
    Set tablerange = Range("H1", Range("H1").End(xlDown))
    For Each cell In tablerange
        If cell.Value = "YES" Then
            If rngTarget Is Nothing Then
                Set rngTarget = cell
            Else
                Set rngTarget = Union(rngTarget, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    If Not rngTarget Is Nothing Then rngTarget.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
Sub deleteRows()
    With ActiveSheet.Columns("H:H")
        .Replace What:="YES", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Never use this approach. This is a time eater.

Comment: @Blackcat if you have hundreds of thousand of rows yes but for several hundred of rows and with the current advancement of cpus today its almost neglible